# Undefined в массиве после цикла

Tags: массивы, javascript, циклы

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять почему после преобразования каждого элемента массива в цикле результат содержит элемент `undefined`

здесь http://jsfiddle.net/umEeG/
в методе colorize я преобразую массив и вывожу его через `alert`. Первое значение как ни странно `Undefined`. Хотелось бы понять откуда оно появилось

```
(function($){
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- options ----------    
$.fn.kalininRainbowText = function(options) {                   
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        colorArray: new Array('#974bff', '#ec11a1', 'navy', 'orange', '#ecb111', 'magenta', '#055d12', '#4bb1ff')
    },options);

    return this.each(function() {
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ properties ---------  
        var self = $(this);

        var colorArrayLength  = options.colorArray.length,
            text = self.text(),
            textLength = text.length;

        init();

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ methods ------------      
        function init(){
            var i,
                letterArray = new Array();

            for(i = 0; i < textLength; i++){
                letterArray[i] = text[i];
            }

            colorize(i, letterArray);   
        }

        function colorize(textLength, letterArray){
            var i,
                newText;

            for(i = 0; i < textLength; i++){
                q = letterArray[i];
                letterArray[i] = '<span>' + q + '</span>';

                newText += letterArray[i];

            }

            console.log(newText);
        }

        function deColorize(){

        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ handlers -----------      
        function onClick(){
            alert(1);
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ events -------------  
        self.on('click', onClick);          
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализируйте переменную правильно.
Замените

```
function colorize(textLength, letterArray){
var i,
    newText;
```

На вот это:

```
function colorize(textLength, letterArray){
var i,
    newText = '';
```

И все заработает, как часы.